# Блокировка запуска программы

Tags: c++, c, windows

Пользователь сам определяет какую программу хочет защитить, при запуске программы под защитой появляется окно блокировки.

[image: Пример]

Как реализовать блокировку запуска программы?

Comment: Речь о вашей собственной программе или вообще о любой? Если последнее, то воспользуйтесь стандартными возможностями администрирования: [например](https://www.technipages.com/prevent-users-from-running-certain-programs).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, меня интересует программный подход

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте рассмотрим два самых простых способа.

первый, простой. Ваша программа подменяет все "нужные бинари". При запуске она спрашивает пароль и запускает заведомо подготовленную, переименованную копию нужной программы.

Плюсы:

- просто сделать
- не зависит от версии ОС.
- супер гибко

Минусы:

- нужно аккуратно пробросить параметры командной строки
- нужно позаботиться о шифровании основного бинаря, что бы пользователь не "обошел".
- любой инсталлятор снесет все.

Второй - зарегистировать свою программу как обработчик exe файлов (точно также как регистрируются на открытие jpg или txt).
Минус один и он очень большой - Сама программа тоже exe... и среда разработки... Отладка превращается в сплошной кошмар.

А вообще, можно обратиться к разработчикам вирусов - они этим промышляют постоянно:)